# C++ Embedded Control Register Template

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, embedded, metaprogramming

My current job has had me doing research into creating classes for arbitrary embedded device registers. Currently I am working with a number of targets with varying register sizes and I would like to standardize (or at least come up with some logical way) of enumerating objects for memory-mapped io, registers, etc.
The current company standard is to place a variable at the register location.

```
volatile uint16_t &register_obj = *reinterpret_cast<volatile uint16_t *>(0x01A02);
```

I read a few papers and discussions on the subject of embedded C++, most notably [this blog post by Niklas Hauser](https://blog.salkinium.com/typesafe-register-access-in-c++/) and this [overview](http://www.eld.leidenuniv.nl/~moene/Home/papers/accu/overload95-register/) providing a comparison and extension of a few other papers. These posts contain further references to a great paper on [representing and manipulating hardware with C and C++](http://www.openstd.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/ESC_SF_02_465_paper.pdf) as well as some mock examples and alternative ideas in [Ken Smith's C++ Hardware Register Redux](https://yogiken.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/c-register-access.pdf).

I further defined a type alias to represent the register width with:

```
/* These define an alias for the largest register that can exist in a 
* sub-module. Where a module (IE: UART) contains an arbitrary number of 
* sub-modules (IE UART_CTL0, UART_CTL1, UART_INTERRUPTS...) as defined in the 
* vendor's datasheet.
*/
#if defined(__MSP430__)
using reg16_t = volatile uint16_t;
#elif defined(__ARM__)
using reg32_t = volatile uint32_t;
#endif
```

The first code snippet then becomes:

```
reg16_t &register_obj = *reinterpret_cast<reg16_t *>(0x01A02);
```

This didn't satisfy me. I realized that "placement new" might be a good fit for my applications as registers and memory-mapped IO are effectively pre-allocated memory sections that I could overlay objects over.

I read up on [variadic templates](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2013/03/variadic_templates/) and spent hours trying to design a template that created and placed an arbitrary type at a specified address, the closest was the following:

```
template <typename T>
T* placeObject(uintptr_t address) {
   return new (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t*>(address)) T;
}
```

but the implementation is effectively a worse version of what I started with. example:

```
reg16_t& control_register = *submodule_new<reg16_t>(0x0160);
```

I tried a struct template and came up with:

```
template<typename T, uintptr_t address>
struct submodule
{
    T &location = *reinterpret_cast<T *>(address);
    // Also needs to implement mutability (access policy)
};
```

this looked promising as it's declaration is exactly what I'm looking for:

```
submodule<reg16_t, 0x0160> control_register_0;
```

but the struct-interfacing is rather awkward:

```
uint8_t ENABLE = 0x4;
control_register_0.location &= ~ENABLE; // this probably doesn't work
```

**My actual questions**

- Are there any good examples of "pure C++" class-based register templates?
- If not, how should I structure the inheritance and construction notation so that it provides a clear intention of my goals?

The end goal for this project is to have sub-modules contain access-policies and the location of data to read and write. These sub-modules would ideally be constructed in a variadic class generator to allow for arbitrarily-many, arbitrarily-sized, interfaces to memory that provide type-safety and access policies (read-only, write-only). Something of the form:

```
// pseudo-code
template<typename base_type, class ...submodules>
class module
{
    // somehow assign submodules to this class
};

module<submodule<reg16_t> UARTControl0, submodule<reg16_t> UARTStatus> UART();

UART.UARTControl0.Write(0x0001);
bool uart_enabled = UART.UARTStatus.read(0x);
```

Comment: The Problem I see is that you sometimes simply shouldn't hide Access restrictions behind a Policy. If you are writing Flash Memory or are Setting MMU internal Registers which are just Windows to an internal Register file then the order of Events Prior to the writes is defining the correctnessof the Code. And worse than that, you sometimes want different Setups depending on optimization, System reaction etc. Opaque Access Methods at this Point are Maybe more abstraction than is good for the end product.